# Candidate for Removal in GAM based on p-value and 0 function

Tags: r, anova, smoothing, gam

I am trying to determine which predictor variables can be removed from a GAM, based on approx. p-values, and by looking at the extent to which the confidence band for an estimated term includes a zero function.
I have a summary that shows every smooth function to be statistically significant:

```r
Family: poisson 
Link function: log 

Formula:
daily_confirmed_cases ~ s(tests, k = 18) + s(vaccines, k = 18) + 
    s(people_fully_vaccinated, k = 18) + s(hosp) + s(icu) + s(ndate, 
    k = 18)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) 7.405421   0.001489    4973   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                              edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
s(tests)                   16.793  16.98  14075  <2e-16 ***
s(vaccines)                16.982  17.00   9744  <2e-16 ***
s(people_fully_vaccinated) 16.923  17.00   7337  <2e-16 ***
s(hosp)                     8.988   9.00   6893  <2e-16 ***
s(icu)                      8.985   9.00   7246  <2e-16 ***
s(ndate)                   16.673  16.96  11156  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.965   Deviance explained = 97.7%
-ML =  19761  Scale est. = 1         n = 460
```

but the plots of two of the smooth terms essentially only contain  the zero function:

[image]

[image]

so I made a model to remove those terms, but the anova test said removing just either  one or increased the deviance, compared to the original model.

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: daily_confirmed_cases ~ s(tests, k = 18) + s(vaccines, k = 18) + 
    s(people_fully_vaccinated, k = 18) + s(hosp) + s(icu) + s(ndate, 
    k = 18)
Model 2: daily_confirmed_cases ~ s(tests, k = 18) + s(vaccines, k = 18) + 
    s(people_fully_vaccinated, k = 18) + s(icu) + s(ndate, k = 18)
Model 3: daily_confirmed_cases ~ s(tests, k = 18) + s(vaccines, k = 18) + 
    s(people_fully_vaccinated, k = 18) + s(hosp) + s(ndate, k = 18)
Model 4: daily_confirmed_cases ~ s(tests, k = 18) + s(vaccines, k = 18) + 
    s(people_fully_vaccinated, k = 18) + s(ndate, k = 18)
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev         Df Deviance
1    372.93      38113                    
2    381.92      44970 -8.9882474  -6857.2
3    381.92      45328 -0.0011262   -357.7
4    390.92      51696 -9.0004878  -6368.8
```

Therefore,  I should stick to the original model with icu and hospital smooth therms included correct?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. the scale of the y-axis on the plots is equal across the plots while it is clear that some variables have much more of an effect than others on the log response. To fix that, set `scale = 0` in your call to `plot.gam()` to get each of the plots on a different scale.
2. all of your smooth terms are statistically significant; why would you drop any? They are all being estimated *not* equal to 0, so why set them to be exactly equal when you delete them? This doesn't make sense from a model development or inference stand point
3. removing a term from the model (even an insignificant one) *must* increase the (residual) deviance of the model. The question is whether it increases it by such a large amount that it would be such an unlikely increase if the true effect of the removed term were == 0. You need to add `test = "LRT"` to the `anova()` call if you want to do a formal test (and get a p value)
4. you probably want to fit the model with `method = "ML"` if you are going to be comparing models with different fixed effects (as per your `anova()`).

Things to deal with:

1. You could add `select = TRUE` to your `gam` call to turn on model selection for you. This will add extra penalties to your smooths so that they can be shrunk out of the model entirely if needed.
2. All your smooths are hitting the upper limits of the possible EDF given the constraints on the size of the basis you imposed. You need to run `k.check(model_object)` to run the test of basis dimension.
3. You are likely missing lagged effects of covariates and lagged values of the response (or something else for autocorrelation), which could enter as smooth terms or in distributed lag form,
4. It's unlikely that counts of disease are Poisson conditional distributed; it's likely the data are overdispersed and you should check that by computing the dispersion parameter by hand using a Pearson or similar estimated of the dispersion and / or fit a model that can handle over dispersion, such as the Negative Binomial via `family = nb()`.